# How do I adapt US investing advice to other countries?

Tags: investing

The 99% of investing resources on the internet seems to be US centric. How would I adapt the ideas I get from the to do investing in other countries? Say for eg, Germany or India.

Comment: This question is a bit close to 'seeking off-site resources' for comfort. That said, there is a [personal finance reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/personalfinance) which has a sidebar with country links to both the countries you mention...

Comment: There is plenty of investing advice out there for other countries. Yes, the internet has more US content than others, and search engines are biased towards the place you are doing the searching. Also good investment advice for e.g. Germany is likely to be in German. You just have to look for that advice.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think it's US-centric? The general principals are pretty universally applicable, even if the specifics vary.

Comment: `The 99% of investing resources on the internet seems to be US centric` - in English, probably, and even that would change if you add a country qualifier to your query.

Comment: There are significant differences in laws concerning investing among different countries. There are also differences in banking practices, stock exchange rules, investment advice, financial planning, etc. If you need resources in Germany or India you should use localized search engines like google.de and google.co.in

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the type of advice. Be mindful of any particular limits, amounts, or rates in the advice, and consider whether these are specific to the U.S. rules/frameworks. Some types of advice, such as "invest in state or municipal bonds to take advantage of their tax-exempt status" would definitely be specific to U.S. tax laws and not necessarily applicable to other countries.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are plenty of resources. E.g. [Reddit Finanzen](https://www.reddit.com/r/Finanzen/) which even has an [Austrian Version](https://www.reddit.com/r/FinanzenAT/). You can ask /search there for country specific advice.

It's kind of obvious there are more English resources, because anyone trying to reach a broader audience will use English. These people will know the details in their specific region, which is why you get answer for [PRIIPS](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117472/how-to-find-equivalent-us-or-worldwide-etfs-that-are-compliant-with-european-pri) etc here on this site as well.

However, most advice is anyhow universally applicable. For example, if you want to understand why passive investment is [usually a good choice](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155284/109107), what the [return of bond ETFs](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/156572/109107) looks like or learn details about an [options theta](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154958/109107) has the same answer no matter where you live.

For short, if you have a specific question, I am almost certain google will find an answer to almost all your problems, especially for such a large and wealthy country like Germany where there are lots of resources as well.

If you have a specific example where you think it doesn't work, please add it to you question so that we can have a look if there is indeed nothing (I'd doubt here).

Comment: I dispute that  much investment advice is equally applicable in many jurisdictions. Bizarre advice about how to pick stocks is equally (in)applicable and should be avoided, but useful advice like how to reduce your tax burden varies a lot.

Comment: Well, since stock picking should be avoided, this advice is universally applicable, no? Taxation obviously varies from country to country but just searching tax German or tax india gives you about 2000 results here. Most likely not all with good answers, but is the same with any online forum where anonymous people answer questions.  Yet, most universities across the globe use similar textbooks (Hull, Zvi Bodie, ...) so it seems there is a considerable amount of overlap....